# Runtime error when running Processing sketch on local device

Tags: android, processing

I'm trying to create a Processing Android App. I'm using Processing 4 and have an Android device hooked p to my laptop in developer to run the Processing sketch on. Processing fins the device and builds the app successfully, but at runtime I get this error:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Rejecting class processing.a2d.PSurfaceAndroid2D that attempts to sub-type erroneous class processing.core.PSurfaceNone (declaration of 'processing.a2d.PSurfaceAndroid2D' appears in /data/app/~~VlADy301fGp8vnYM2AkxTw==/processing.test.sketch_231207b-qZBeLCHHwR202EYQ4uqxlw==/base.apk)
```

I have no idea where to start. I'm using Processing 4 and Android 34.

Comment: This is a known problem, discussed here: https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/729#issuecomment-1657220658  A fix was given by one of the respondents.  It is here: https://github.com/ajavamind/processing-android-410-api-15

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I was googling for hours and never stumbled upon this - it fixed the issue.

Comment: @apodidae that's a great comment. if you could add it as an answer that would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem which has been discussed here: https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues/729#issuecomment-1657220658 . A fix was given by one of the respondents and is here: https://github.com/ajavamind/processing-android-410-api-15 .